# iOS: Detecting if User Canceled "Add to Calendar" in event kit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, eventkit

I have a button in my app that brings up the EventEditViewControllerWithEventStore view. When The user presses done, the event is added to the calendar and I present a notification when it's added. However, how can I tell if the user canceled? As of now the notification is presented regardless if the user pressed done or cancel.

This is what I have so far:

```
- (IBAction)addEvent:(id)sender {

    EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    if([eventStore respondsToSelector: @selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)]) {

        [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL permissionGranted, NSError *error) {

            if (permissionGranted){

                NSLog(@"PERMISSION GRANTED.");

                [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(presentEventEditViewControllerWithEventStore:) withObject:eventStore waitUntilDone:NO];
            }

            else {

                NSLog(@"NO PERMISSION.");

                [TSMessage showNotificationInViewController:self withTitle:@"Oops! Permission Required" withMessage:@"In order to use this feature, please enable calendar access for this app under settings." withType:TSMessageNotificationTypeWarning withDuration:TSMessageNotificationDurationAutomatic withCallback:nil atPosition:TSMessageNotificationPositionTop];    

            }
        }];
    }

    else {

        // If device is > 6.0
        [self presentEventEditViewControllerWithEventStore:eventStore];
    }
}

- (void)presentEventEditViewControllerWithEventStore:(EKEventStore*)eventStore
{
    EKEventEditViewController *vc = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] init];
    vc.eventStore = eventStore;

    EKEvent* event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];

    //Pre-populated Info
    event.title = @"Event title";
    event.startDate = [NSDate date];
    event.endDate = [NSDate date];
    event.URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"];
    event.notes = @"Event Notes Can Go Here.";
    event.allDay = YES;
    event.location = @"Earth";
    event.availability = EKEventAvailabilityTentative;
    vc.event = event;
    vc.editViewDelegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma EKEventEditViewDelegate

- (void)eventEditViewController:(EKEventEditViewController*)controller
          didCompleteWithAction:(EKEventEditViewAction)action {


    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    [self performSelector:@selector(eventAddedSuccessfully) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];

}

#pragma TSMessages

- (void)eventAddedSuccessfully {

    NSLog(@"Event was successfully added.");


    [TSMessage showNotificationInViewController:self withTitle:@"Success!" withMessage:@"The event was added to your calendar." withType:TSMessageNotificationTypeSuccess withDuration:TSMessageNotificationDurationAutomatic withCallback:nil atPosition:TSMessageNotificationPositionTop];


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `delegate` method of your `EKEventEditViewController` to `self` and then, add the following method to catch it.

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark EKEventEditViewDelegate

// Overriding EKEventEditViewDelegate method to update event store according to user actions.
- (void)eventEditViewController:(EKEventEditViewController *)controller 
          didCompleteWithAction:(EKEventEditViewAction)action {

    NSError *error = nil;
    //EKEvent *thisEvent = controller.event;

    switch (action) {
        case EKEventEditViewActionCanceled:
            // Edit action canceled, do nothing. 
            break;

        case EKEventEditViewActionSaved:
            // When user hit "Done" button, save the newly created event to the event store, 
            // and reload table view.
            // If the new event is being added to the default calendar, then update its 
            // eventsList.
            [controller.eventStore saveEvent:controller.event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];
            break;

        case EKEventEditViewActionDeleted:
            // When deleting an event, remove the event from the event store, 
            // and reload table view.
            // If deleting an event from the currenly default calendar, then update its 
            // eventsList.
                        break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    // Dismiss the modal view controller
    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

Also, make sure your your interface in header file in conforming to the EKEventEditViewDelegate like below:

**.h file**

```
@interface EventViewController : UIViewController <EKEventEditViewDelegate> {}
```

Here is how to check to see if you were granted permission to add/modify events:

```
EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];    
if([store respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)]) {
    [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
            //Access not granted-------------
            if(!granted){

            }

            //Access granted
            }else{

            }
    }];
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you. I just have one quick question. I want to trigger an action if the user didn't give the app permission to access the calendar, but for some reason nothing happens when I put it inside the else{} only the NSLog works.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but my problem is that in the else{} statement when I do an NSLog it shows up, but when I place a UIAlertView there it doesn't trigger. Do you know why? It's only in the else statement, that nothing happens.